# paging of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a  gridview where i have allowed paging.
but when i click second page the gridview disappears
here is the c# code :

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        OdbcDataAdapter adpState = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT CALL_NO,TDATE,
        ID_NO,NAME,CONTACT,DEPARTMENT,ISSUE,STATUS FROM TBL_ITHELPDESK 
        WHERE (STATUS IS NULL OR STATUS <> 'CLOSED') AND  TDATE= TO_DATE('" +
          txtDate.Text.ToString().Trim() + "','MM-DD-YYYY')", con1);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adpState.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();    
    }
```

can anyone help to find where i'm going wrong

Comment: is this the same code that you are using to bind you grid first time?

Comment: i did  not  write  a  seperate  function for binding the data. am i supposed to do that?

Comment: yes it is better that you write a method for that code that repeats

Comment: ok. is that the reason the second page dont appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check multiple things.

1. Check the query with the one that is working, Is it Same?
2. Check the con1 variable is defined outside of any other method.

Define `con1` in a class not in a method, something like that

```
 odbcConnection con = new odbcConnection(ConectionString);
```

Comment: i've defined the con1 variable like this before page_load String con1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ToString();